# TwinCAT3 build on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, twincat

Is it possible to build TwinCAT3 solution on Jenkins?
I have tried it with msbuild and devenv.com.

msbuild: MSBuild does not support *.tspproj
devenv.com .tspproj: The application which this project type is based on was not found

Answer (score 3):

You can't build the a PLC project using MSBuild, because it is not build with MSBuild but through the CodeSYS compiler.

You can however [build the whole solution](https://github.com/tcunit/TcUnit/issues/7#issuecomment-559178327) using:

`start /wait "" "%ProgramFiles(x86)%/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/Common7/IDE/devenv.exe" project.sln /Rebuild "Debug|TwinCAT RT (x86)" /Out logfile.log`.

**Edit 23 May 2020**

Or you can build a single project from a solution with ([see MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/project-devenv-exe?view=vs-2019)).

`start /wait "" "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" "C:\path\to\solution.sln" /Project "relative\path\to\PLC.plcproj" /Rebuild "Debug|TwinCAT RT (x86)" /Out logfile.log`

Answer (score 1):

Hi Eva and welcome to stack overflow.
Yes, it's possible but you have go through the [TwinCAT automation interface](http://download.beckhoff.com/download/document/automation/twincat3/AutomationInterface_pdf_EN.pdf). With the automation interface you can access most of the functions (including building) in TwinCAT but through a programming or scripting language, which you in turn can run from Jenkins.

I've written a series of posts consisting of four parts of how you can run TwinCAT compilations from Jenkins, and they are available here:

https://alltwincat.com/2018/07/05/ci-cd-with-twincat-part-one/

https://alltwincat.com/2018/07/26/ci-cd-with-twincat-part-two/

https://alltwincat.com/2018/08/28/ci-cd-with-twincat-part-three/

https://alltwincat.com/2018/10/04/ci-cd-with-twincat-part-four/

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. I will look at it.

Answer (score 0):

TwinCAT automation interface also works great with powersell