# Beckhoff TwinCat3 CI/CD Docker

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, containers, plc, twincat

So what I'm looking for is some way to build my PLC project in a Docker Container for a nice and easy CI/CD.

From what I found online it is not possible to perform a command line compilation of Beckhoff TwinCAT.

I did find this post on stackoverflow:

[TwinCAT3 build on Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59284842/twincat3-build-on-jenkins)

But this requires devenv.exe which is not provided in build tools.

Anyone got a way of building my project within docker?

Answer (score 0):

Building a TwinCAT PLC project programmatically can be done using the [TwinCAT automation interface](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/content/1033/tc3_automationinterface/index.html) although it is not trivial. This is what is discussed in the post you linked. You must install [TwinCAT XAE](https://www.beckhoff.com/en-en/support/download-finder/software-and-tools/#) and then write a (C#) program that builds and deploys your PLC project. I wrote such a program for my customers.

Because a PLC program has real-time requirements it cannot run everywhere. It does not run in Windows but besides Windows such that it can meet its RT requirements. This Windows/TwinCAT combination only runs in specific virtualization platforms/modes. I ran TwinCAT PLC projects in Windows Server Hyper-V and VMware for my customers. You probably will have to run docker on Windows Server Hyper-V in Hyper-V isolation mode.